# Better alternative to Try Catch madness?

Tags: c#

Is there a better alternative to the try catch madness in the code below? I'm collecting all kinds of similar system information and have several more of these annoying try catch constructions and would very much like to get rid of them.

Note that this actually makes sense. Not all the process information in the try blocks can get retrieved, and what's not available is just optional anyway, while at the same time it's not acceptable to skip what is available, hence why there isn't just one try catch pair.

If only those try catch statements could go into the `Append()` method.

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    try { Append(proc.Threads.Count); } catch { }
    try { Append(proc.Id); } catch { }
    try { Append(proc.ProcessName); } catch { }
    try { Append(proc.BasePriority); } catch { }
    try { Append(proc.StartTime); } catch { }

    Append(proc.HandleCount,
        proc.PrivateMemorySize64,
        proc.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64,
        proc.PagedMemorySize64,
        proc.PeakPagedMemorySize64,
        proc.PeakVirtualMemorySize64);
}
```

Comment: You could add a `SafeAppend<T>(Func<T> getter)` method which does `try { Append(getter()); } catch { }` and then use that in your original code: `SafeAppend(() => proc.Threads.Count);`

Comment: How many of these lines can *actually* fail, though? In my tests, only `StartTime` could result in "access denied". The other information appears to be publicly available regardless of whether you have access to the process or not. (This is assuming `Process` is the well-known `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.)

Comment: @V0ldek It’s quite difficult to modify .NET’s built in classes or properties that can throw.

Comment: A word of warning, if this is going to be called quite frequently, and will be potentially catching lots of exceptions, that could become quite a performance hit. Exceptions are rather expensive so should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: @Denis Schaf - Why is it bad?

Comment: What makes you think that if for example `proc.Id` were to fail to get the process ID that you could possibly succeed in getting the process name, base priority, etc.? In other words: Why not just using a single try-catch for all Appends?

Comment: And please catch relevant exceptions. You don't want a `NullReferenceException` to go unnoticed.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert  - Depends on the OS. I have more of these in my program, and some of these (drive information) fail under Linux, but not Windows.

Comment: @ DavidG - It's only called once per program execution.

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong and your code is safe, you are protected and those functions can raise exceptions.  @MartinCostello's approach looks elegant, I would vote for that.

Comment: @elgonzo - I don't know, and I don't care because I want a foolproof method of doing this for all the cases I need and then not have to think about it anymore. Perhaps not a good idea.

Comment: Well, you could just use one try-catch surrounding all your Appends. What would be less fool-proof then?

Comment: elgonzo - Yes, I know that (see original question), but I want to make sure that I don't miss anything.

Comment: Another option would be to use compiler directives to only execute the commands you know will work per platform. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743808/how-to-use-custom-preprocessor-directives-in-net-core) or [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2018/11/05/platform-conditional-compilation-in-net-core/) on how to do that. Now you just wrap the entire thing in a single try/catch.

Comment: @DavidG - And then I'd have to work out what works on what. It's much easier if I have just one Append() method that just always works without breaking.

Comment: @Martin Costello - Your suggestions seems to do the job, thanks!

Comment: Yup, personally I'd much rather know what works on each platform though...

Comment: @DavidG - It's just not an option, because some of these try catches just fail on Linux, while the platform supports those functions. Microsoft's documentation doesn't seem to offer any info on that. Then there's also the problem of how many platforms and platform versions there are. A huge pain that can be entirely avoided by a single method thanks to Martin Costello.

Comment: No, platform versions won't have any difference, it either works on a platform or it doesn't. Your approach is a hammer to something that needs more finesse. As you see in the answer from Patrick, just test each platform, and if the docs are wrong/missing, please update them - they are all available to edit on Github.

Comment: @ DavidG - But what do I gain from that except more code? Sometimes simpler is better.

Comment: Silently eating exceptions is evil.

Comment: @ 3Dave - Not in this case. What's not available is optional. The information I'm collection is hashed with Sha256 to generate a seed for a non-cryptographic PRNG that doesn't depend on the system's cryptographic RNG. So in this case the information that can't be retrieved really is optional, hence why it doesn't matter. It's a bit of a niche case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, your approach in general is wrong, but it will work. You can 'optimize' this in readability by using a method:

```
private void AppendSafe<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    T val;

    try
    {
        val = f();
    }
    catch { return; }

    Append(val);
}

AppendSafe(() => proc.Threads.Count);
AppendSafe(() => proc.Id);
AppendSafe(() => proc.ProcessName);
AppendSafe(() => proc.BasePriority);
AppendSafe(() => proc.StartTime);
```

But I would argue to catch relevant exceptions. You don't want a `NullReferenceException` to go unnoticed.

Also, since exceptions are expensive, it is better to work out which properties are available on what platforms and test for that. At least you will minimize performance impact when calling this frequently.

Comment: All exceptions are caught in my code, I've made sure to check each property specifically for that. The code is only run once per program execution, so that's absolutely not a problem.

Comment: In that case you factor out all logging etc on first chance exceptions, etc. but good point overall.

Comment: Exceptions can be an issue at scale, (maybe an extreme example, but Troy Hunt had his [issues with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049604/can-you-return-an-http-response-from-an-authorizeattribute-without-throwing-an-e)). I think our general point is to try to avoid them if you can. This answer is great, but I'd much prefer to understand, per platform, what should and shouldn't be working.

Comment: @DavidG As I suggested indeed ("it is better to work out which properties are available on what platforms and test for that").

Comment: This is a niche case. The information is only collected for seeding a big state non-cryptographic PRNG. What is and isn't available on what platform doesn't seem so important. Perhaps I should have made that more clear in the original question.